# c50 code called exit with value 1 AND Error: C5.0 models require a factor outcome

Tags: r, csv

So I am working on an Rmd using a credit.csv . I have the following code

```
#install.packages("C50")
library(C50)
credit_model = C5.0(credit_train[-2],     # field 21 is the default, and we don't want that as part of the tree
                    credit_train$default)  
credit_model
```

which displays this error

```
Error: C5.0 models require a factor outcome
```

but if I try to convert default to factors like this :

```
#install.packages("C50")
library(C50)
credit_train$default<-as.factor(credit_train$default)
credit_model = C5.0(credit_train[-2],     # field 21 is the default, and we don't want that as part of the tree
                    credit_train$default)  
credit_model
```

it displays this error:

```
c50 code called exit with value 1

Call:
C5.0.default(x = credit_train[-2], y = credit_train$default)

Classification Tree
Number of samples: 900 
Number of predictors: 20 

Tree size: 0 

Non-standard options: attempt to group attributes
```

i really dont knowwhat to do there are no missing fields in the dataset

Comment: Please share your data set for reproducing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The internal logic of the model has been removed. But you can use the following to see it:
summary(credit_model)

Comment: Hello, as stated by @ranamahmud a sample of data should be shared (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The `summary` statement is useless if the dataset we're referring to is not available.